# How to extract specific rows depending on part of the strings in one column in R

Tags: r

When I use R, I try to extract specific rows which have some specific strings in one column.
The data structure as following

```
ERC1    20679  14959  9770  RAB6-interacting protein 2 isoform
```

I want to extract the rows which have `RAB6` in the last column. That column still has some other words besides `RAB6` so I can not use `column = "RAB6"` to get them. It's just like a search function in excel. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You could use `grep` i.e. `df1[grep('RAB6', df1$lastcolumn),]`

Comment: Thanks for notifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data frame is `df`:

```
df[grep("^RAB6", df$column),]
```

If not all values start with `RAB6` remove the`^`.

Comment: @akrun Thanks for pointing this out. I'll edit the answer so that it becomes more general.

Comment: @akrun So, if you think you have the right answer, please post an answer and not a comment. It's pretty clear stated when you comment: "Avoid answering question in comments".